# Trigger Google DocumentApp Script Upon Edit of SpreadsheetApp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

**Using Google Apps Script, is there a way to have a Google Documents file update automatically whenever a Google Sheets file is edited?**

I've got a Google DocumentApp file with a script that gets data from a Google SpreadsheetApp file.  I'm looking to create a script to automatically update the DocumentApp file whenever the SpreadsheetApp file is edited.

This is the code I'm using currently:

```
function updateDocumentOnEditTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SheetID);
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('UpdateDocument')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onEdit()
      .create();
}
```

Running the `updateDocumentOnEditTrigger` function doesn't seem to trigger the `UpdateDocument` function, which works as it should when manually run.

Comment: I would like to understand about your goal. But I cannot understand about `I want to trigger that DocumentApp script to run whenever the SpreadsheetApp is edited in any way.`. Can I ask you about it? By the way, I think that `openById` cannot be used with the simple trigger using `onEdit()`. If you want to use `openById` by the OnEdit event trigger, please use the installable OnEdit event trigger. How about this?

Comment: @Tanaike I want to create a trigger script for the DocumentApp file so that anytime the SpreadsheetApp file is edited, the DocumentApp file is updated. I've changed the script as follow:  ```function updateDocumentOnEditTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SheetID);
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('UpdateDocument')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onEdit()
      .create();
}```  I wrapped the other function inside this function and placed it outside and neither seems to update the DocumentApp file.

Comment: It sounds like you want to create an `onEdit` trigger on the **SpreadsheetApp** that will then update the **DocumentApp**. So that anytime the **SpreadsheetApp** is edited, code will run that will then edit/update the **DocumentApp**. Is that right?

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan That's correct.  I'm a novice with Google Scripts.  I've inserted the above installed trigger as advised in my 'UpdateDocument' DocumentApp script.  Is this correct or would I need a separate script for the SpreadsheetApp file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*In order to run a `DocumentApp` script on edit of a Spreadsheet, the `On edit` installable trigger attached to the Spreadsheet must be used.*

#### More Information:

As per the Simple Triggers documentation, there are some restrictions which need to be taken into account. In particular:

> They can modify the file they are bound to, but cannot access other files because that would require authorization.

As a result, the `onEdit(e)` trigger function can not be used. There is however an installable trigger which can be created, with settings set up such that it can fire on edit.

#### Code:

With the following function in the script bound to the Spreadsheet file:

```js
function updateDocument() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById('DOCUMENT_ID');
  // here you can put your code that edits the document in the way you want.
}
```

You can create an installable trigger which runs on the edit of the Spreadsheet. You will need to run the code at least once before setting up the trigger however - this is because `DocumentApp` needs authorisation and you need to grant it!

###Setting up an Installable Trigger:
With the code set up, you can create the installable trigger by completing the following steps:

From the Apps Script editor view for the bound Spreadsheet script, follow the path `Edit > Current project's triggers`. This will open the triggers for the project in a new tab or window.

In the bottom left, click on the `+ Add Trigger` button, bringing up the `Add Trigger` modal. From here, set up the trigger with the following properties:

- Choose which function to run: `updateDocument`
- Choose which deployment should run: `Head`
- Select event source: `From spreadsheet`
- Select event type: `On edit`

And click `Save`. This will set up the trigger such that your Document editing function will run each time the Spreadsheet is edited.

#### References:

- [Google Apps Script - Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Simple Triggers - Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions)
- [Google Apps Script - Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)